# Arabic characters are not recognized

Tags: java, php, android, database, arabic

I'm retrieving text from database in android studio using java and php. English texts get displayed successfully however when I add arabic to database it is displayed as boxes in Android. Can you guys please help me sort this out.

*it works perfectly in html browser page. but in android it does not. However its xml file is set to UTF8. it is supposed to work. Can anyone find out the problem?*

**Main.java**

```
  public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
//phpconnection declaration
TextView resultView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //phpconnection starts from here

    StrictMode.enableDefaults();

    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    getData();
//button

    Button insert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getData();
        }
    });
    //phpconnection ends here
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



//phpconnection again starts
public void getData() {
    String result = "ERROR!\n Please turn on mobile data or Wi-Fi in settings";
    InputStream isr = null;

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost ("http://balochplay.zz.mu/test/index.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute (httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldn't connect to database");
    }

    //convert response to string

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try {
        resultView.setText(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Couldn't set text.");
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="Error! \nPlease Connect to Internet"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

**please guide me how to fix it.**

I have seen other similar questions on the forum i tried but it didn't work for me.

---

My database settings are:

The table collation is `utf8_general_ci` and its type is `MyISAM`, and the columns `(id, name)` inside it: type is **int for id** and **mediumtext for Name** and collation is utf8_general_ci

ex. the output should be السلام عليكم but it's Ù„Ø¨Ø¨ÙŠ

**phpcode**

dp

```
<?php
 //create connection
$con=mysqli_connect    ("mysql.hostinger.ph","u242667358_abc","123456","u242667358_test");


//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

?>

index

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require_once('db.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM BalochiNames ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";   

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo stripslashes($row['BalochiName']);

}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean my Android Studio, Are you talking about the IDE preview or when you actually run the application on your device?

Comment: i'm running application on my device. It's operating system version is lolipop 5.0

Comment: It is maybe an encoding error, did you tried to show arabic text from string.xml file ?

Comment: no! can you please guide me on how to do that in string.xml file

Comment: Can you try this, `yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your
   chars");`

Comment: @Diode, when i write something in android:text="السلام عليكم" then my device displays the text i have no problem in writing arabic. but when i retrieve data from database android does not recognize it.

Comment: @AmirDora I tried to recreate your issue using your code. But I can not access your http://balochplay.zz.mu/test/index.php.

Comment: @Diode you can access it now.. u242667358_abc pass: 123456 http://sql18.hostinger.ph/phpmyadmin/sql.php?token=df99d189af6bec88e1e59bd48a2877c6&db=u242667358_test&table=BalochiNames

Comment: @Diode its a test database. feel free to access it!  using the username and passwrd i gave u. and I appreciate for taking the time and to find a possible solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Arabic Language in Android](http://blog.amr-gawish.com/39/arabic-language-in-android/)

It has full guide how to show Arabic in Android.

Also you need to include a few classes in your Android Project given [here](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper).
Follow the guide and you'll know what you've to do.

A simple example

```
AssetManager manager=this.getAssets();
manager.open("tahoma.ttf");
TextView tv=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(manager, "tahoma.ttf"));
tv.setTextSize(50f);
tv.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape(" الحمد لله hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`String appname = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("your Text in Arabic));`